# How can I find (.class) file in newest version eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, class

You know, in newest version eclipse, navigator is deprecated.

So I don't know how to find (.class) file.

I did a search, but filters setting of package explorer is different from what is described in other post..

[image]

Comment: Deprecated does not mean removed. The Navigator View is still there.

Comment: how to activate Navigator view? I already clicked window - show view - Navigator.
but it didn't work.

Comment: The Navigator view appears in the bottom pane rather than the left - are you looking at the correct place.

Comment: oh my.. Thank you, I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'Project Explorer' and turn off the 'Java output folders' filter to see the output folders.